# jqueryui slider not working inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have number of bootstrap popover and some of them have jqueryui slider as content of the bootstrap popover and that slider is not working

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/yasirhaleem/43qfkjtb/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.triggerOverlay').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var cont = $this.data('toggle');
      return $('#'+cont).html();
    },
    trigger: 'manual'
  }).click(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();
});


  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // always hide them all.
  var popov = $(".popover");
    if (!popov.is(e.target) && popov.has(e.target).length==0 ){
            $('.triggerOverlay').popover('hide');
    }    // if e.target has a popover toggle it.
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('triggerOverlay')) {
      $(e.target).popover('toggle');
    }
  });
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
});
```

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/5kuB8/9/ , may help.

Comment: i have seen this, i don't only have slider within popover but other contents too and there are lot of dynamic popover

Comment: btw i'm using popover within primefaces

Comment: Then try witout PrimeFaces first and if it is relevant, post an [mcve] that proges that

Comment: @Kukeltje jsfiddle in question is without PrimeFaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution to my question posting reply to my own question hope it will be helpful for others.

if someone has better solution please post or suggest in comments.

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yasirhaleem/s1ytug1c/

this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/5kuB8/9/ was not helpful for me i had different schenario, my html was already generated i was using different solution for popover and than we decided to use bootstrap popover and we run into this problem.

All i needed was a callback function below code extend the popover and adds callback function

**Extending popover**

```
var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function() {
    tmp.call(this); if (this.options.callback) {
        this.options.callback();
    }
}
```

**Popover Call**

```
$('.triggerOverlay').popover({ 
html : true,
callback: function () {
            $('.slider').slider();
},
content: function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var cont = $this.data('toggle');
  return $('#'+cont).html();
},
trigger: 'manual'
```

});

**HTML**

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="user-profile-overlay" class="triggerOverlay">button</a><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="user-profile-overlay" class="customoverlay">content goes here<div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```